# HomeKit Accessory and services name(s)?

Tags: ios, esp32, homekit, ios-homekit

We are developing a Smart Home / IoT product that integrates into HomeKit. The integration is mostly done and interation with the product works great. We have only one problem: naming inside the home app.

Each time we add one of our devices to the home app, the services names are changed to the name of the accessory. Here is an example with the homekit tree:

```
Accessory
    Service: Accessory Information
        Characteristrics: name = "my accessory"
    Service: Light Bulb
        Characteristics: name = "light 1"
    Service: Light Bulb
        Characteristics: name = "light 2"
    Service: Light Bulb
        Characteristics: name = "light 3"
    Service: Light Bulb
        Characteristics: name = "light 4"
    Service: Temperature Sensor
        Characteristics: name = "temperature sensor 1"
```

When adding this device with 4 lights and 1 temperature sensor to homekit, all the services inside the app gets renamed "my accessory". They do not keep their name. It is especially strange since HomeKit knows about the names of the services since if I modify the name of the first light, HomeKit will suggest (in the background on the text input in gray) to rename it "light 1".

I know that my characteristics declaration are correct because I verified it with the HomeKit Accessory Tester.

What I can do so that the services offered by my device are not renamed to the name of the accessory itself ?

Thanks in advance.